# How to Select more than WMI Query

Tags: wmi, wmi-query

Hello I'm using Visual Studio C++ .

This will explain alot :

```
IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
    bstr_t("WQL"), 
    bstr_t("SELECT SerialNumber FROM Win32_DiskDrive"),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
    NULL,
    &pEnumerator);

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Query for harddisk sn failed."
        << " Error code = 0x" 
        << hex << hres << endl;
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;               // Program has failed.
}

IWbemClassObject *pclsObj;
ULONG uReturn = 0;

while (pEnumerator)
{
    HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, 
        &pclsObj, &uReturn);

    if(0 == uReturn)
    {
        break;
    }

    VARIANT vtProp;

    // Get the value of the Name property
    hr = pclsObj->Get(L"SerialNumber", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
    wcout << "HDD SN : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
    VariantClear(&vtProp);

    pclsObj->Release();
}
```

This will Cout the serial number of Harddisk.My main question how i can select multiple queries at the same time so that i can output more than one result

I need to add for example this  "SELECT SerialNumber FROM Win32_BaseBoard" and output both HDD and Motherboard serial number at the same time

Help xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`WQL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't support query more than a WMI class at same time. So you must call the `ExecQuery` method for each class.